# How to directly assign character array to stdin in c?

Tags: c, stdin

I want to directly push a character array into the standard input stream `stdin`, but cannot think of a syntax that works. The closest I can think of is

```c
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
```

which reads the contents from a file "input.txt" into the FILE pointer stdin. But I don't like this approach because 1) it relies on creating an additional file, 2) I have to worry about creating one file for each of such requests, which can turn into a ton of txt files in a folder just for this simple purpose of assigning some character array to stdin.

Is there a better, more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Might be better to redesign your code such that it's not hard-coded to read from stdin, but a custom-provided file descriptor.

Comment: @iBug thank you for your suggestion. In my case, I am deliberately doing this to test a program that involves user input. Basically, I want to exhaust all possible user inputs to bash the program.  Do you think there is a better alternative for my task?

Comment: Investigate how much pushback you can do in your environment with `ungetc()`.  Some systems (IIRC, the older Unix systems like Solaris, HP-UX, AIX) have very limited pushback — the standard only guarantees one byte and they adhere to a limit close to that.  Many modern systems (Linux, macOS) give you significant buffers — up to about 4 KiB under testing, and I didn't push it beyond that.  See [`ungetc()` — number of bytes of pushback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7814816/15168) for the details (from a few years ago, but the test code is in my answer there).

Comment: If you want to test a program with user input, it's still a better idea to redirect stdin to a file or another controlled source *from the outside* (e.g. a shell script) than trying to fiddle `freopen` or `ungetc` or what have you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaken about this assumption:

> which reads the contents from a file "input.txt" into the FILE pointer stdin.

This is not what `freopen` does! What this does is *replacing* the file/connection of `stdin` itself.

This might be a perfectly legitimate thing to do, specifically if your program isn't expecting to have its input being redirected by its creating process.

Within the C standard library you're somewhat limited in what you can do. But if you're allowed to use POSIX syscalls, then you could to the following:

1. `dup` the file descriptor of `stdin` into a temporary.
2. create an anonymous pipe using the `pipe` syscall.
3. `dup2` the reading end of the pipe over the `stdin` file descriptor.
4. `write` the character array to the writing end of the pipe.
5. restore `stdin` by `dup2` the file descriptor saved in step 1) over `stdin`
6. close the temporary file descriptor obtained in 1

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right that my understanding of `freopen` was not entirely correct. I am fine with writing hypothetical inputs into an `input.txt` file and then pointing `stdin` to the file. However, this process only fulfills one program test for me. I need to perform dozens of such tests, and I wonder if there is a way to avoid dozens of separate text files lying in the test folder. Your second suggestion regarding POSIX is enticing but something new to me. I need to read up on that and then come back. I hope the learning curve isn't that steep.